# Select2 : Is it possible to use default translation and noResult key?

Tags: translation, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Here is my select2 working fine :

```
$('.select2-customers-search').select2({
   language: {
      noResults: formatNoCustomer
   }
});
```

Here is my default translation :
`$.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'fr');`

When I remove noResults from the select2, translation works fine, but when I add it the translation does not work anymore.

Is there a chance to use both ?